# using `?:` in the output stream

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, cout

I want to integrate the `?:` operator in the output stream. Here is code

```
bool a;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
  a = rand() % 2;
  std::cout << "a= " << (a) ? "true\n" : "false\n";
}
```

But the output is

```
a= 1a= 0a= 1a= 1a= 1a= 1a= 0a= 0a= 1a= 1
```

The problem is, there are no **new line** and **string**. What should I do?

Comment: Put parentheses between them. `(a ? "true\n" : "false\n")`.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but the parentheses in `(a)` aren't needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because the output operator `<<` has higher [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the ternary operator `?:`. So for the compiler it's the same as

```
(std::cout << "a= " << (a)) ? "true\n" : "false\n";
```

You need to explicitly put the parentheses at the correct place:

```
std::cout << "a= " << (a ? "true\n" : "false\n");
```

---

Or as `a` already is a `bool` you can use `std::boolalpha` to print it directly:

```
std::cout << "a= " << std::boolalpha << a << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some parentheses to override the default precedence rules:

```
std::cout << "a= " << ((a) ? "true\n" : "false\n");
```